# Move elements from one vector to another vector in c++

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, element

The question didn't make sense and wanted to delete it, since stackoverflow doesn't allow that I have reword it properly for future reference.

I was trying to write a game which required 4 marbles per a hole in 8 holes on a board. To start the game, one has to pick a hole and share it marbles clockwise with the rest of the holes. I wanted to use vectors to represent each hole on the board ("which isn't the smart way to go about it at all, as looking at it now I would have used just one vector to represent the holes!!! I was very new to c++ then.").

**Hole1** is a vector filled with 4 elements of marbles.
// GameMar its the game marble.

std::vector TempV; //represented a hand to help move the marble "it wasn't necessary at all"

//Since I'm sharing all the marbles in **Hole1**, I decided to move all the marbles into the **TempV** which will leave *Hole1* empty while **Hole2**, **Hole3**, **Hole4**, **Hole5** will have 5marles each.

TempV = std::move(Hole1); //("I could've just used the **Hole1** and pop the marbles on to the other Holes")

The Question was how was I able to share the marble across the other holes?

Comment: Please post code rather than attempt to describe it. Your question is really, really hard to read as it is. There's a help button in the [edit]or, give it a look.

Comment: Better now? I'm not sure what you mean in the last paragraph, please review.

Comment: I tried to add code to clarify, but then I hit that last paragraph and gave up :(

Comment: Guys I don't want to more all the elements in the TempV to The Hole2 or 3, I only want to more just single one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the last element from `TempV` to `Hole2`:

```
Hole2.emplace_back(std::move(TempV.back()));
TempV.pop_back();
```

Alternatively, using copy constructors:

```
Hole2.push_back(TempV.back());
TempV.pop_back();
```

Obviously you need to check that `TempV.size() > 0` before you attempt this.

Frankly, `move` may be overkill, given that you seem to be dealing with pointers.

Comment: That.... that doesn't move.  `Hole2.emplace_back(std::move(TempV.back()));`?

Comment: @MooingDuck - He didn't *say* "move" when referring to `Hole2`, but I'll update it nonetheless.

Comment: @Unsigned you guys did a good job to try and come up with a solution. well done.